# Django South migration history causing an integrity error

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration, django-south

My south migration history table is causing integrity errors every time I try to run a new migration.  Here is the error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "south_migrationhistory_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(40) already exists.
```

So far, this is only happening locally.  I have deleted the database and rebuilt a number of times, and each time all existing migrations run smoothly.  But as soon as I create a new migration, I get this error again.

Migration 40 happens to be a third party migration (djangoratings), so I don't believe it is a problem with that migration file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: update djangoratings. They have fixed the error in the latest release

Comment: I'm already at the latest djangoratings, 0.3.7.  According to Andrew Godwin, this can happen if you have ever manually edited the south_migrationhistory table in your database.  Lesson learned.

Answer (score 9):

How about

`SELECT setval('south_migrationhistory_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM south_migrationhistory));`

That worked for me.

You probably should do a `pg_dump` beforehand, just in case it all goes wrong.

I'm using postgres, you might need to use a slightly different command to update your database sequence for other databases.